# How to login to different server from shell script

Tags: shell-script, grep

I am writing script to check disk usage above the threshold for different servers. But when I execute the script it is asking only for user passwords and not giving the proper output.

The script I have:

```
#!/bin/sh
USERNAMES=("username-for hostname1" "username-for hostname2")
PASSWORDS=("passwd-for hostname1" "passwd-for hostname2")
output1=/tmp/disk-usage.out
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "HostName            Filesystem                Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on"
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------"
for server in `more /imp/scripts/servers.txt`----list of the servers
do
output=`ssh $server df -Ph | tail -n +2 | sed s/%//g | awk '{ if($5 > 10) print $0;}'`
echo "$server: $output" >> $output1
done
cat $output1 | grep G | column -t
rm $output1
```

It is giving me output like: `sh tt.sh`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HostName            Filesystem                Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
root@hostname1's password:

root@hostname2's password:

10.89.218.179:  /dev/mapper/vg_vm-lv_root  5.5G  2.6G  2.7G  50  /




__________________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Can you provide more details, how is it not expected behaviour? Seems pretty ok to me.

Comment: You need to use SSH RSA keys AND run ssh-agent

Comment: @Prvt_Yadav it was just asking for password not giving the df -h output.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro how we can do that...

Comment: @NehaBhargava isn't `10.89.218.179: /dev/mapper/vg_vm-lv_root 5.5G 2.6G 2.7G 50 /

`, a df -h output?

Comment: You have syntax errors on lines two and three of your script. (`sh` doesn't have arrays; did you intend to use `bash`, `ksh` or `zsh` perhaps?)

Comment: It might be worth considering the use of an actual monitoring system.

Comment: @Prvt_Yadav its giving output only for 1 server i am testing for 2 servers :sh tt.sh
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HostName            Filesystem                Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
root@10.89.218.50's password:
root@10.89.218.179's password:
10.89.218.179:  /dev/mapper/vg_vm-lv_root  5.5G  2.6G  2.7G  50  /
not giving output for 10.89.218.50 and its asking for password.

Comment: Because maybe the size occupied is not more than 10%. Have a look at the awk command. @Neha Bhargava

Comment: @Prvt_Yadav it was more than 10%
[root@localhost ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_localhost-lv_root
                       44G  2.1G   39G   6% /
tmpfs                 1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   54M  406M  12% /boot from 10.89.218.50

Comment: @Prvt_Yadav and its asking for password also....for both servers which we don't want in scripting we are making it for monitoring purpose

Comment: @Prvt_Yadav and in 10.89.218.179 also we are having 2 mount point above 10%[root@VM ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_vm-lv_root
                      5.5G  2.6G  2.7G  50% /
tmpfs                 499M     0  499M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   85M  375M  19% /boot
/dev/sdb               70G  4.3G   62G   7% /imp

Comment: Neha Bhargava please don't put updates here in the comments. It makes it very difficult for people to work out what's the most current information. Instead, please [update your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/635305/edit) as necessary. (Don't just write "update" and put the extra information at the end, but include it in the question properly, as if you'd written it like that originally.)

Comment: Please do not abuse "we", it makes me uncomfortable. The responsibility and work towards the issue is yours, and your responsibility and work alone.

Comment: @Rui using "we" like this is common usage in some variants of English. It doesn't necessarily include us here on unix.SE

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in line `cat $output1 | grep G | column -t`, You want to grep only sizes which are in `G`, however in your expected output you also want to see the output for `M`. You can remove this grep command or use `grep -- [GM]`.